# Creating Pair RDDs

Tags: apache-spark

From the below RDD , I would like to create a pair RDD.

```
val line = sc.parallelize(Array("2,SMITH,AARON"))
```

I used the below code:

```
val pair = line.map(x => (x.split(",")(0).toInt, x))
```

The output generated is `Array[(Int, String)] = Array((2,2,SMITH,AARON))`

But I would like the desired output to be `Array[(Int, String)] = Array((2,SMITH,AARON))`

Pls help me out. 
I am a newbie.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easy way to do this is to split and get the array in each position

```scala
line.map(r => {
   val split = r.split(",")
   (split(0).toInt, (split.tail.mkString(",")))
})
```

Comment: Thanks.This worked..

I have another question in continuation to the given solution.

The basic idea is to create a key-value pair.
If the input RDD has multiple elements like "2,SMITH,AARON,CALIFORNIA,US,....."
My requirement is Key to be "2" and the rest are values.
As per your given code, should i use split(1),split(2),split(3),split(4).....split(n) or is there any other way?
Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your above question

Answer (score 1):

Just take the rest:

```scala
val pair = line.map(x => x.split(",") match {
  case Array(x, xs @ _ *) => (x.toInt, xs.join(",")}
})
```